# How do I clear the data in a DataList control before binding the data?

Tags: asp.net

I have  a requirment:  in a gridview  we have the option to clear the contents  before  binding (gridview.rows.clear). In a  similar  way  we  have  any option  to clear the datalist control before  binding data to it.

If there is no data in the source datatable (before binding I check if the record count is less than  zero) then **I need  to  show  a message saying there  is no data  to  be  displayed**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FooterTemplate` of the `DataList` to display an empty data message.

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" runat="server" Text="No data to be displayed"></asp:Label>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Then in the `PageLoad` event.

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
DataList1.DataSource = dt;
DataList1.DataBind();

if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    DataList1.ShowFooter = true;
}
```

To use the FooterTemplate you must bind the DataList. If you wish to display a message before binding, as stated in your question, you can use a Label with its visibilty set to false and toggle the visibility based on the number of rows in your DataTable.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" runat="server" Text="No data to be displayed" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    this.lblEmpty.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks  for the  replay  Phaedrus
 tried   the  above  way  what ever  u  said.

  when i  give  search  for the data which is there  it displayes  the data in datalist control. when is ther no  record  for the search  it display   the   footer telling empty data

  but the  old  contents  which  where binded eariler is not yet  cleared . along with the old data  it is showing the footer  message
 thank  you

Comment: How are you binding your DataList? At which point in the Page Life Cycle? Page_Load? Page_Init? Adding some relevant code to your question would help us more easily solve your problem.

Comment: i am  binding in  my button clcik event

Comment: Are you rebinding on every click? Or only if the DataTable contains rows? It sounds like the DataList is being repopulated from ViewState, this is why you are seeing the previous search results in the DataList.

Comment: yes  rebinding  at  every  click  i am  doing  search    thing if any record is  found i will be  displaying  in datatlist control

Comment: but here i need  to  show  my footer template  message  telling 

 "that data not is  empty found"
if(datatable.rows.count=0)
{ 

MyDataList.DataSource = null;
MyDataList.DataBind();
}
 but  here   my  footer template  message is not getting  displayed